# Read part of texture using SharpDX

Tags: textures, directx11, sharpdx

I have a `Texture3D`. I want to read a part of it from CPU side. (I'm using the SharpDX toolkit (v2.5.1).)

My data is always 0, but the output shows no errors.

This is the source texture:

```
testTex = Texture3D.New<float>(GraphicsDevice, wx, wy, wz, PixelFormat.R32.Float, texDat, TextureFlags.ShaderResource, sdx11.ResourceUsage.Default);
```

I'm trying to read part of it here:

```
tempFloat = new float[1];
TextureDescription stagedTexDesc = new TextureDescription()
{
    Height = 1,
    Width = 1,
    Depth = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    ArraySize = 1,
    Format = testTex.Format,
    Usage = sdx11.ResourceUsage.Staging,
    CpuAccessFlags = sdx11.CpuAccessFlags.Read | sdx11.CpuAccessFlags.Write,
};
texNew = Texture3D.New(GraphicsDevice, stagedTexDesc);

deviceContext.CopySubresourceRegion(testTex, 0, new sdx11.ResourceRegion(iHPos.X, iHPos.Y, iHPos.Z, iHPos.X + 1, iHPos.Y + 1, iHPos.Z + 1), texNew, 0);
texNew.GetData(tempFloat);
```

`tempFloat[0]` value is always 0.0. The `GetData` method performs `Map` and `Unmap` of the resource automatically

If I try to call `GetData` on the original texture, it seems to get the data correctly.

Also, is there a better way to read the data?

Comment: This could be a bug. Could you provide a reproducible simple VS project on github issues https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues so that we can have a look at this?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try to create reproducible project this evening.

Comment: I have reported an issue and uploaded a sample project.  https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/281

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a SharpDX bug best discussed with the developers.

Comment: Actually it wasn't a bug, I posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I used deviceContext in wrong way.
It should have been either initialized like this:

```
var deviceContext = (SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext)GraphicsDevice;
```

Here is the explanation what I did wrong here:

```
var deviceContext = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext(GraphicsDevice);
```

When creating a new DeviceContext, it is actually creating a deferred context, more relevant in multithreaded scenarios. In your case, all commands issued on this newly created deferred context were in fact no-op (because a deferred context needs a special pattern to replay it on the immediate context).

Another solution would be to use directly:

```
GraphicsDevice.Copy(testTex, 0, new sdx11.ResourceRegion(iHPos.X, iHPos.Y, iHPos.Z, iHPos.X + 1, iHPos.Y + 1, iHPos.Z + 1), texNew, 0);
```